# How do I multiply the data of 2 textbox inside a while loop in php with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Once I use the script I did in JavaScript, it only changes the value of the first textbox inside a while loop. Here is my php code:

```
<?php 
  $edittable=$_POST['selector'];
  $N = count($edittable);
  for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
  {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory where assetid='$edittable[$i]'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      extract($row);
?>      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><?php echo $assetdesc; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $serialno ?></td>
          <td><select class="form-control" name="qtyunit" id="qtyunit" onchange="calculate()"  required>
                  <option>----</option>
                  <?php
                  $qtyfirst = 1;
                for($new = $qtyfirst ; $new <= $assetqty; $new++){
                   ?>
                  <option><?php echo $new; ?></option>
                  <?php
                }
                     ?>
                     </select></td>
          <td><?php echo "₱".number_format((float)$purchaseprice, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
          <input value = "<?php echo $purchaseprice; ?>" name="hiddencost" id="hiddencost" hidden>
          <td><input class="form-control" name="totalcost" id="totalcost" readonly></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
var myBox1 = document.getElementById('qtyunit').value; 
var myBox2 = document.getElementById('hiddencost').value;
var result = document.getElementById('totalcost'); 
var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
result.value = myResult;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to parse the strings to Numbers. There are many ways, `unary +`, `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number`, ..

Comment: oh, i really want to multiply. sorry forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 0):

the biggest problem I can see here without testing is that you are using the same `HTML id attribute` multiple times when looping your output with PHP.
you can only use one `id` name once per document. if you want to work with multiple html elements at once you have to use classes, for example your select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="qtyunit" class="qtyunit" onchange="calculate()"  required>
    <option>----</option>
    <?php
        $qtyfirst = 1;
        for($new = $qtyfirst ; $new <= $assetqty; $new++){
    ?>
    <option>
        <?php echo $new; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

and then in your `javascript`:

```
var myBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('qtyunit').value;
```

**note:** this example might not be what you want to achieve - I just wanted to point out your primary mistake.

Comment: my code is already working, i can select the quantity and display the total, but that only works on the first data, what i want is that it will work also with the next data

Comment: yeah, but you are still generating html elements with the same ID multiple times which is wrong. you'll have to enumerate your IDs.

Answer (score 0):

so by far i have solved my problem using this method.

php code:

```
<?php 
$edittable=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($edittable);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory where assetid='$edittable[$i]'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  extract($row);
  ?>      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><?php echo $assetdesc; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $serialno ?></td>
          <td><select class="form-control" name="qtyunit[]" id="qtyunit<?php echo $assetid; ?>" onchange="calculate(<?php echo $assetid; ?>)"  required>
                  <option>----</option>
                  <?php
                  $qtyfirst = 1;
                for($new = $qtyfirst ; $new <= $assetqty; $new++){
                   ?>
                  <option><?php echo $new; ?></option>
                  <?php
                }
                     ?>
                     </select></td>
          <td><?php echo "₱".number_format((float)$purchaseprice, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
          <input value = "<?php echo $purchaseprice; ?>" name="hiddencost[]" id="hiddencost<?php echo $assetid; ?>" hidden>
          <td><input class="form-control" name="totalcost[]" id="totalcost<?php echo $assetid; ?>" readonly></td>
          </tr>
            <?php 
          }
        }
            ?>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(id){
var quantity = document.getElementById('qtyunit'+id).value;
var price = document.getElementById('hiddencost'+id).value;
var sum = parseInt(quantity,10)*parseInt(price,10); 
document.getElementById('totalcost'+id).value = sum;
}
</script>
```